# How to add a custom taxonomy to a custom post type's document tab

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy and wanted to add it to the side-menu of my portfolio custom post type (in the admin area). My custom taxonomy is not loading, but the default one ('category') does. What did I miss?

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies' );    
function add_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
      'related_service',
      'portfolio',
      array(
        'label' => 'Related Services',
        'public' => true
      )
    );
  }

add_action( 'init', 'register' );
    function register() {
      register_post_type( 'portfolio', array(
        'label' => 'Portfolio',
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category', 'related_service' )
      ) );
    }
```

Comment: besides the double ")" on the first line, your code works well on a fresh installation of WordPress.

Comment: The missing ")" in the question has been corrected. For clarity, I want to be able to select a category in the document tab on the right hand side when a portfolio CPT is opened. I only see that functionality for Categories in my installation.

Comment: If you're using the Block Editor you also need to add `'show_in_rest' => true` for the taxonomy. You only have it for the CPT currently.

Comment: @WebElaine If you add it as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer, thank you :).

Comment: @WebElaine can you post your answer as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Block Editor you also need to add `'show_in_rest' => true` for the taxonomy. You only have it for the CPT currently.